# Added jQuery code but no animation?

Tags: jquery

I have added the below code to my index.php and template.css. I see the image but there is no animation, am I missing something stupid here???

Thanks

```
**inside <head> tag**

</style>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<script>
var left = $(window).width() - $('#about').offset().left;
$("#about").animate({
opacity: 0.60,
left: left,
}, 5000, function () {
// Animation complete.
});
</script>

**inside <body> tag**

<div id="about"> <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" title="about">
<img src="images/models/about.png" alt="news" width="75" height="150" /></a>
</div>

**Inside css**

#about {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
right: 300px;
 background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: you didn't wait for the image to exist before you selected it. `$([]).animate()` is equivalent to what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to wrap your code within jQuery.ready() function since you have to wait for DOM to be fully loaded.

```
$(function() {

    var left = $(window).width() - $('#about').offset().left;
    $("#about").animate({
        opacity: 0.60,
        left: left,
        }, 5000, function () {
            // Animation complete.
   });

});
```

```js
$(function() {

    var left = $(window).width() - $('#about').offset().left;
    $("#about").animate({
        opacity: 0.40,
        left: left,
        }, 2000, function () {
            // Animation complete.
   });

});
```

```css
#about {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 100px;
 background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="about"> <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" title="about">
  <img src="http://www.daralmarjaan.com/images/about.png" alt="news" width="75" height="75" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: it works brill :) can the animation be made to come from top and not go left? so on screen come downwards and maybe growing in size slightly? – Dillon just now edit

Comment: @Dillon Sure! you can.

Comment: www.corblimeyfashion.co.uk you will see a pink pathway Im after the model images about 5 of them to appear to be coming down it, so maybe fadein small growin until reaching the bottom. Each stopping a short distance from each other...dont know if you can help with that but Id be grateful if you can help out. Thanks

Comment: yeh, thats going top to down and out, im after the image fade in and come down at an angle to make it look like its coming down the pink path then stop on it, not go off screen?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you need exactely but check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JPDqA/)

Comment: thats getting clser, instead of coming direct down from the top, is it possible to have it coming diagonally, so 45 degree angle top/right? the fade at start to full image is cool, its just the angle now now to come from?

Comment: Thats ace :) if I wanted to change the angle slightly how do I do that?, also how do I make the distance it travels shorter...appreciate your help...

Comment: If you look here www.corblimeyfashion.co.uk you will see the image is way too far right, I tried right: 500px; but it changes the angle, Im trying to get the image as if its coming down the pink pathway, its starting to look cool just getting the alignment correct and the distance shorter? cool stuff :)

Comment: You can change the angle by changing height and right values. if you want to make the distance shorter just decrease the height value. See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/442Gw/)

Comment: Thats brill, cant thank you enough for this, if you look at site now its on top and coming down, I had to do a right: 700px to move the image more to the left side, not sure if there is a better way than this? but again thanks for all your help, much appreciated mate :)

Comment: If I look on firefox the image is on the path but on IE its up in the air and going upwards not down? any idea on this mate? thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37955/discussion-between-fouad-fodail-and-dillon)

Answer (score 2):

Include the code inside `$(document).ready()` because you have to wait that dom element are ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var left = $(window).width() - $('#about').offset().left;
  $("#about").animate({
    opacity: 0.60,
    left: left,
  }, 5000, function () {
      // Animation complete.
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: works brill :) can the animation be made to come from top and not go left? so on screen come downwards and maybe growing in size slightly?

Comment: to come from top you can put for example top:200px(or some values that you consider adapt) into the anmation instead of left, and insert: width:100px to make a new width for example, but this is another question I think, accept the answer that solve your original problem and open a new question for the problem of animation @Dillon